# Filtering out shorter sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list

I have a nested list:

```
[['spam', 'eggs'],
['spam', 'eggs', '111'],
['spam', 'eggs', 'foo'],
['spam', 'eggs', '111', 'bar'],
['spam', 'eggs', 'foo', 'bar']]
```

What I need is an algorithm to get indexes of shorter sublists, all elements of which are contained in longer ones. In this example algorithm should return:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can the individual lists contain duplicate values? If so, is a list that contains the same element three times considered a "sub-list" of a longer one, that contains that element only once? And how do you count "longer" - by number of elements, or of distinct elements? (Also - apparently you don't care about the ORDER of the elements in a list; right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way may be to use double `for` loop in same list and check with `.issubset` for those when not equal `index`:

```
my_list = [['spam', 'eggs'],
            ['spam', 'eggs', '111'],
            ['spam', 'eggs', 'foo'],
            ['spam', 'eggs', '111', 'bar'],
            ['spam', 'eggs', 'foo', 'bar']]

indexes = []
for index1, item1 in enumerate(my_list):
    for index2, item2 in enumerate(my_list):
        if index1 != index2:
            if set(item1).issubset(item2):
                indexes.append(index1)
                break

print(indexes)
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert each sublist to a set, and use the helpful [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) method.  This will *not* work if you have duplicate elements in your lists that you need to preserve.

```
x = [set(i) for i in x]

x = [i
 for i, e in enumerate(x)
 if any(e.issubset(j) and i != k
        for k, j in enumerate(x))
 ]

# [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: I'm running it on your sample and getting `[0, 1, 2]`, did you remember the `and i != k`? If you forget that, sets will be considered subsets of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

```
out_index = [i for i in range(len(my_list)) 
             if any(set(my_list[i]) < m 
             for m in [set(j) for j in my_list])]
```